# imshow.set_data() not working for FuncAnimation

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, matplotlib, scipy

I am writing a program for 2D FDTD light propagation, in this code, when I run the program with `ax.imshow()` command in the animate function, the program works fine whereas when I use the  `im.set_data()` command, it gives me a blank image. Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong? Also, can somebody tell me how to set the colormap at the beginning so that I dont have to update it during the animation loop. The point is I don't want the `imshow()` command to draw everything everytime the loop is run.
Thanks for all the help. I am learning programming please suggest me what to do.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


xdim = 100        
ydim = 100
epsilon = np.ones([xdim,ydim])*8.854187817*10**(-12)
mu = np.ones([xdim,ydim])*4*np.pi*10**(-7)
c = 299792458
delta = 10**-6
deltat =  delta/(c*(2**0.5))

Hz = np.zeros([xdim,ydim])
Ey = np.zeros([xdim,ydim])
Ex = np.zeros([xdim,ydim])


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
im = ax.imshow(Hz)

Hz[xdim/2,ydim/2]=1

def init():
    im.set_data(np.zeros(Hz.shape))
    return

def animate(n, *args, **kwargs):
    Ex[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]=Ex[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]+(deltat/(delta*mu[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]))*(Hz[1:xdim,0:ydim-1]-Hz[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1])
    Ey[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]=Ey[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]-(deltat/(delta*mu[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]))*(Hz[0:xdim-1,1:ydim]-Hz[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1])

    Hz[1:xdim,1:ydim]=Hz[1:xdim,1:ydim]+(deltat/(delta*epsilon[1:xdim,1:ydim]))*(Ex[1:xdim,1:ydim]-Ex[0:xdim-1,1:ydim]-Ey[1:xdim,1:ydim]+Ey[1:xdim,0:ydim-1])
    if(n==0):Hz[xdim/2,ydim/2]=0
    #im.set_data(Hz)                 
    ax.imshow(Hz)     # Delete this command and try running the program with the above command. 
    return

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames = 200, interval = 10, blit = False, repeat = False)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your first version was working just fine also.  The problem was that because `im` is initialized with an array of zeros, the `vmin` and `vmax` for the colorscale were both zero.  Updates to `im` after that using `set_data` did not update `vmin` and `vmax`, whereas `ax.imshow` automatically rescales the color ranges.  If you set the color ranges at the beginning to something reasonable, it works fine:

```
ax.imshow(Hz, vmin=-0.2, vmax=0.2)
```

That's the only thing you need to change from the code in the question to make it work (with `im.set_data` in the animation function).

Answer (score 1):

I got the program to work by making a few changes, though i cannot understand why it is not working the way i wrote it in the question. Here is what i changed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


xdim = 100
ydim = 100
epsilon = np.ones([xdim,ydim])*8.854187817*10**(-12)
mu = np.ones([xdim,ydim])*4*np.pi*10**(-7)
c = 299792458
delta = 10**-6
deltat =  delta/(c*(2**0.5))

Hz = np.zeros([xdim,ydim])
Ey = np.zeros([xdim,ydim])
Ex = np.zeros([xdim,ydim])



Hz[xdim/2,ydim/2]=1

def init():
    global fig, ax, im
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes()
    im = ax.imshow(Hz, cmap="jet")
    im.set_data(np.zeros(Hz.shape))
    return

def animate(n):
    Ex[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]=Ex[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]+(deltat/(delta*mu[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]))*(Hz[1:xdim,0:ydim-1]-Hz[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1])
    Ey[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]=Ey[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]-(deltat/(delta*mu[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1]))*(Hz[0:xdim-1,1:ydim]-Hz[0:xdim-1,0:ydim-1])

    Hz[1:xdim,1:ydim]=Hz[1:xdim,1:ydim]+(deltat/(delta*epsilon[1:xdim,1:ydim]))*(Ex[1:xdim,1:ydim]-Ex[0:xdim-1,1:ydim]-Ey[1:xdim,1:ydim]+Ey[1:xdim,0:ydim-1])
    if(n==0):Hz[xdim/2,ydim/2]=0
    im.set_data(Hz)                 
    return

init()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 500, interval = 10, blit = False, repeat = False)
fig.show()
```